# AWS Cognito Google IdP - Custom OAuth Consent Screen

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I'm working on setting up Google as an IdP for my Cognito User Pool. I'm following [this AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-google-social-identity-provider/).

Even though I'm only selecting "non-sensitive scopes" (opened, profile, email) when configuring the OAuth app, Google is then saying that it requires verification.

The AWS guide linked above says:

> For Authorized domains, enter amazoncognito.com.

I've entered this as an authorized domain, but since I've done that, Google is now saying that in order to verify the app, I need to "verify ownership of the following domain" (amazoncognito.com). Clearly, I cannot do this, as I do not own that domain.

Am I missing something here? It seems that AWS and Google have set this up in a way that makes it impossible to verify a Google OAuth app for use with Cognito.

Comment: Did you add a logo or display name? That's also a reason for verification to [become necessary](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615).

Comment: I did add those, yes. Can those not be used with Cognito then?